# ¿Existe una forma más eficiente de realizar mi programa en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter, ipython, julia

¡Hola!

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en **Julia** y me encontré con el siguiente ejemplo de *array*:

```
julia> [(i,j) for i=1:3 for j=1:i]
6-element Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64},1}:
(1, 1)
(2, 1)
(2, 2)
(3, 1)
(3, 2)
(3, 3)
```

Usualmente, programo en **python**. Se me ocurrió generar el mismo array en **python**, y este es mi programa:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(1,4,1)
list = []
for i in a:
    list.append(i)
    par = [[i,j] for j in list]
    print(par)
```

Mi pregunta es: ¿Podemos realizar un programa en python más eficiente?

Quizás mi programa está muy pedestre :( y tiene sus detalles (estoy generando una lista y etc...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python tiene *list comprehensions* con una sintaxis muy similar a la que muestras en el ejemplo de Julia. Usando esta característica de python muchos casos de creación/transformación/filtrado de listas puede escribirse sin utilizar bucles explícitos y de forma muy sucinta (y ligeramente más veloz en tiempo de ejecución).

En tu caso:

```py
>>> [(i,j) for i in range(1,4) for j in range(1,i+1)]
[(1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
```

También, en lugar de crear una lista en memoria puedes crear un generador, que sólo vaya dando los elementos a medida que los pidas. Es tan sencillo como usar paréntesis en lugar de corchetes en la expresión anterior:

```py
>>> mis_pares = ((i,j) for i in range(1,4) for j in range(1,i+1))
>>> mis_pares
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f5488c2ebf8>
```

Como ves, `mis_pares` no es una lista, ni una tupla, sino un generador, esperando a ser invocado. Los datos se van generando al vuelo cuando los consumes dentro de un for, como en:

```py
>> for par in mis_pares:
>> ... print(par)
(1, 1)
(2, 1)
(2, 2)
(3, 1)
(3, 2)
(3, 3)
```

Eso sí, una vez agotado el generador no puedes volver a usarlo en otro `for`.

**Actualización** Una nota sobre eficiencia. La implementación en forma de *list comprehension* no sólo es más compacta (y para mi más legible, aunque eso va en gustos), sino también ligeramente más eficiente por la forma en la que es convertida a bytecodes por el intérprete.

He tomado tiempos de ejecución, y la versión "comprehension" tarda en promedio un 86% del tiempo de lo que tarda la versión "bucles explícitos" (y un 51% del tiempo de lo que tarda la solución propuesta por el OP).

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

def genera_lista_comprehension():
    return [(i,j) for i in range(1,4) for j in range(1,i+1)]

def genera_lista_explicitamente():
    lista = []
    for i in range(1,4):
        for j in range(1, i+1):
            lista.append((i,j))
    return lista

def genera_lista_op():
    result = []
    a = np.arange(1,4,1)
    list = []
    for i in a:
        list.append(i)
        par = [[i,j] for j in list]
        result.append(par)

t1 = timeit.timeit(stmt='genera_lista_comprehension()', globals=globals())
t2 = timeit.timeit(stmt='genera_lista_explicitamente()', globals=globals())
t3 = timeit.timeit(stmt='genera_lista_op()', globals=globals())
print(t1/t2)
print(t1/t3)
```

> 0.8628578678773673
>   0.5170212530629336

Comment: Bueno, `for i in range(1, 4)` sigue siendo un _bucle_.

Comment: Por supuesto, me refiero a bucles explícitos. Pero es que además las _list comprehensions_ son ejecutadas por el intérprete de forma diferente a los bucles explícitos, con el resultado de que son ligeramente más rápidas.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con JLDiaz. No conocía *list comprehensions* en python, y sí, es bastante similar con julia. Definitivamente mejoraste el programa y me diste muy buena información y ejemplos. ¡¡Muchas gracias!!!
Sigo trabajando en ello y comparando con **Julia**...